# Unknown number of strings (in letters) in the input

Tags: c++, string

I want to write a program in which the names of `n` different chemical elements are read in the same line in the input (where `1 ≤ n ≤ 17` and `n` is also read in the input) (the names are made apart by a space). The names of the chemical elements should be stored in different strings for further uses.

As `n` is unknown, I don't know how to make something like an "array of strings". Of course I should not make 17 different strings `st1,st2,st3,...` :D.

Can you please help me? Any help will be high appreciated and they will help me a lot.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: search something along lines: read content of file into std::vector using std::copy.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That's an answer, not a comment.  (Although I would phrase it as [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)`<`[`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)`>`)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to read in a line and split it with spaces. Try something such as this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string input;
    std::getline(std::cin, input); // takes one line, stops when enter is pressed
    std::stringstream ss(input); // makes a stream using the string
    std::vector<std::string> strings;
    while (ss >> input) { // while there's data left in the stream, store it in a new string and add it to the vector of strings
        strings.push_back(input);
    }

    for (std::string s : strings) {
        std::cout << "string: " << s << std::endl;
    }
}
```

You give input such as `H He Li`, terminated by hitting enter, and the strings are stored in `strings` (printed in last loop for demonstration).

Edit:

I now see that you want to read the number `n` in the input, too. In this case, you don't need the `stringstream` solution. You can do this instead:

```
int main()
{
    int amount;         
    std::cin >> amount;    // read in the amount
    std::vector<std::string> strings;
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        std::string s;
        std::cin >> s;          // read in the nth string
        strings.push_back(s);   // add it to the vector
    }

    for (std::string s : strings) {
        std::cout << "string: " << s << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And pass input such as `3 H He Li`.

Comment: I ran it on Ideone and I really got what I want -- thank you very much! However, when I compiled on Dev-C++ I got the error message `[Error] range-based 'for' loops are not allowed in C++98 mode`. I haven't changed any settings in the software since the installation. Do you have any hints for me?

Comment: Also, is there any ways to perform like this `Input: 3 H He Li  |  Output: He Li H` (we can decide what will be in the first place)? Or make an index number for each string? I'm sorry, I'm just a newbie and I'm very bad at `vector`.